# Extracting Twitter profiles based on page followed

Tags: data-request, api, social-media

Is there any way to extract twitter handles, bio and location of people following a account?

Comment: Do you mean a specific Twitter page?

Comment: @oliver frost   Yes I was looking for a particular twitter page. Your answer helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this information is publicly available from the Twitter REST API. You will need to register an application on https://apps.twitter.com. You can make the calls with Python or R.

My R example:

```
library(twitteR) # install.packages("twitteR")

# Authenticate 
api_key <- "a"
api_secret <- "b"
access_token <- "c"
access_token_secret <- "d"

# This creates an auth file in your working directory, so you will need to run this at least once before your first ever load.

setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret) 

# Get the page information
yourUser <- getUser("ConsolidataLtd")

# Get that user's Twitter followers.
yourUser.Followers <- lookupUsers(yourUser$getFollowerIDs())
yourUser.Followers <- twListToDF(yourUser.Followers)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API endpoints you want are, for example

1. [getfollowers](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids)
2. [getuser](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/user)